# How to keep updating cloud kit record in swift?

Tags: swift, location, cloudkit

My app needs to update users current location to cloud server
So how to update users current location to cloud server?
I tried to use saveRecord but it doesn't work 
and error occurred

```
error:Optional(<CKError 0x17005eea0: "Server Record Changed" (14/2037); "Error saving record <CKRecordID: 0x1458bb9c0; FASVSE10761FDM:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)> to server: Protection data didn't match">)
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You first have to fetch the record, then change it and save it back. If you get the same error, then the record is changed by someone else. You can get the changed record from the error or you could just fetch it again. Then again apply the changes and save it to CloudKit