# How to overwrite CloudKit existing data in Swift?

Tags: swift, cloudkit, overwrite

I have to overwrite existing data in CloudKit

I have tried to use `saveRecord` and it doesn't really work for me.

In my case, I just have to overwrite a single data.

So how can I do?

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    if locationEnable == true {
    if loaded == true {
        let location = locations.last! as CLLocation

        let location2 = locations.last!
        var a:String?
        if(Data.count != 0 ){ a = Data[0].valueForKey("identity") as? String}
        else {a = Data3!.valueForKey("identity") as? String}
        let id = CKRecordID(recordName: a!)
        let locationRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Driver", recordID: id)
        locationRecord.setObject(location2, forKey: "X")
        locationRecord.setObject(a!, forKey: "Identity")
        AddRecordToCloud(locationRecord)
    }
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState != .Active {
        print("Background Updating")
    }
    }
}
func AddRecordToCloud(record:CKRecord){
        let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
        publicDatabase.saveRecord(record, completionHandler: { (record:CKRecord?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if(error != nil){print("error:\(error)")}
            else {print("saving")}
        })
    }
```

here is the error:

```
error:Optional(<CKError 0x7fb858f5ba80: "Server Record Changed" (14/2004); server message = "record to insert already exists";
```

Comment: Update your question with relevant code and details about the problem you are having.

Comment: Please don't duplicate [your own post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907061/how-to-keep-updating-cloud-kit-record-in-swift)

Comment: i have just updated thank you:)

Comment: OK, now there's code. What problem are you having with it? Saying "it doesn't really work" is not helpful. In what way doesn't it work? If there is an error, update your question with the output of printing the error.

Comment: @JeffLeung Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm stuck with it too.

Comment: @JeanLeMoignan yes i solved it

Comment: @JeanLeMoignan try using CKOperation and it will be solved

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch the record, then change the data in it and save that same record back.

Comment: and i got this error
error:Optional("Error saving record <CKRecordID: 0x145dbe890; FASVSE10761FDM:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)> to server: Protection data didn\'t match")